# python.exe crashes while executing query from server

Tags: python, mdx, olap, pywin32, adodbapi

I'm trying to execute tiny mdx query from Analysis Service server at work.
Server provides data via ms ole db, not odbc specification, thats why i use adodbapi library.

Here's the function i use to obtain result from query execution:

```
def mdx_query (query):
    conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLAP; \
                         persist security info=true; \
                         Data Source=***; \
                         initial catalog=analyse;")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
    except (adodbapi.Error, adodbapi.Warning) as e:
        print(e) 
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    conn.close()
    del conn

    return result
```

Primitive single-value queries works perfectly well:

```
select 
[Physical Stock PCS] on 0, 
[Goods].[Categories].[ALL] on 1 
from [analyse]
```

If i got syntax error it also just give me adodbapi.Error message and it's fine.

But if I try to execute more complex queries like:

```
select 
[Physical Stock PCS] on 0, 
[Goods].[Categories].[Level 01] on 1 
from [analyse]
```

[Goods].[Categories].[Level 01] have more than one dimension and i always got python.exe APPCRASH message no matter what.

I tried both python 2 and 3, running in jupyter and console mode,pandas.read_sql_query method. Result is always the same - i get APPCRASH window.

How to cure crashes and finally execute complicated queries?
Any help is appreciated!

UPD:here's error window. Can't change it to EN.[Appcrash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVcyA.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Added screenshot. Doesn't mean a thing to me either.

Comment: How many values will fetchone get?

Comment: Well the only queries i can actually execute give me axactly one value. More complicated queries crash python